# SHIBBOLETH SP - Shibboleth handler invoked at an unconfigured location - Shibboleth.sso/Session/

Tags: configuration, saml-2.0, shibboleth

I am trying to get shibboleth configured.  When I go to https://mysite/secure/index.php, it works properly, I can authenticate, etc. but when I go to https://mysite/Shibboleth.sso/Status (or any other https://mysite/Shibboleth.sso/*) I get the following message:

```
shibsp::ConfigurationException

The system encountered an error at Mon Jul 10 12:06:32 2017

To report this problem, please contact the site administrator at root@localhost.

Please include the following message in any email:

shibsp::ConfigurationException at (https://mysite/Shibboleth.sso/Session/)

Shibboleth handler invoked at an unconfigured location.
```

My shibboleth2.xml is as follows (comments removed for brevity):

```
<SPConfig xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
        xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
        clockSkew="1800">
    <ApplicationDefaults entityID="https://mysite/shibboleth"
            REMOTE_USER="eppn">
        <Sessions lifetime="28800" timeout="3600" checkAddress="false"
                relayState="ss:mem" handlerSSL="true"
                cookieProps="https">
            <SSO entityID="https://idp.testshib.org/idp/shibboleth">
                SAML2 SAML1
            </SSO>
            <Logout>SAML2 Local</Logout>
            <Handler type="MetadataGenerator" Location="/Metadata"
                signing="false"/>
            <Handler type="Status" Location="/Status"
                acl="127.0.0.1 ::1"/>
            <Handler type="Session" Location="/Session"
                     showAttributeValues="true"/>
            <Handler type="DiscoveryFeed" Location="/DiscoFeed"/>
        </Sessions>
        <Errors supportContact="root@localhost"
                logoLocation="/shibboleth-sp/logo.jpg"
                styleSheet="/shibboleth-sp/main.css"/>
        <MetadataProvider type="XML" 
            uri="http://www.testshib.org/metadata/testshib-providers.xml"
            backingFilePath="testshib-two-idp-metadata.xml"
            reloadInterval="180000" />
        <AttributeExtractor type="XML" validate="true"
            path="attribute-map.xml"/>
        <AttributeResolver type="Query" subjectMatch="true"/>
        <AttributeFilter type="XML" validate="true"
            path="attribute-policy.xml"/>
        <CredentialResolver type="File" key="my_key"
            certificate="my_cert" extractNames="false"/>
    </ApplicationDefaults>
    <SecurityPolicyProvider type="XML" validate="true"
        path="security-policy.xml"/>
    <ProtocolProvider type="XML" validate="true"
        reloadChanges="false" path="protocols.xml"/>
</SPConfig>
```

I have examined every config file I can find, every setting I can think of.
I turned on debug mode for native.logger and shibd.logger but not found anything.

What is wrong? or where should I look?

Comment: This is on Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache2

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually with the way Apache is configured.  It was rewriting urls to add a / at the end of each url.  so `https://mysite/Shibboleth.sso/Session` became `https://mysite/Shibboleth.sso/Session/`.  It is always the minor things!

Since the Apache configuration is necessary for another portion of the project, I changed the  Location attribute to add a slash at the end and it worked perfectly!  HT- Scott Cantor on Users@shibboleth.net mailing list!